# MVC Url.Action causes NullReferenceException in post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to have a button on my form page that takes me back to the previous view that requires a parameter, I'm passing a `ViewModel` into the view with the assigned value I'm using. If the button is un-commented the button works fine but the forms post sends a `NullReferenceException`, and if the button is commented the form works exactly as I want.

## The button that breaks the form

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Assignments","Session", new { Model.CourseName })'">Go Back</button>
```

## The Controller Code

```
public IActionResult CreateAssignment(string courseName)
    {
        CreateAssignmentModel assignmentModel = new CreateAssignmentModel();
        assignmentModel.CourseName = courseName;
        return View(assignmentModel);
    }

[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateAssignment(CreateAssignmentModel assignment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(assignment.CourseName);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(assignment.CourseName);
        }
    }

public IActionResult Assignments(string courseName)
    {
        var assignments = storedProcedure.getAssignments(User.Identity.Name, courseName);
        var AssignmentsView = new AssignmentsViewModel{CourseName = courseName};

        foreach (var Assignment in assignments.ToList())
        {
            AssignmentsView.Assignments.Add(Assignment);
        }
        return View(AssignmentsView);
    }
```

## The Model Code

```
public class CreateAssignmentModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AssignmentName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AssignmentDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TotalPoints { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}
```

## The Form with Button

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Assignments","Session", new { Model.CourseName })'">Go Back</button>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
                <h4>Create an Assignment</h4>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="AssignmentName" class="control-label">Assignment Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="AssignmentName" class="form-control" placeholder="Assignment Name" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="AssignmentName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="AssignmentDescription" class=" control-label">Assignment Description</label>
                    <input asp-for="AssignmentDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Assignment Description" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="AssignmentDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="TotalPoints" class=" control-label">Total Points</label>
                    <input asp-for="TotalPoints" class="form-control" placeholder="Points" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="TotalPoints" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DueDate" class=" control-label">Due Date</label>
                    <input asp-for="DueDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Due Date" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DueDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry for the lack of brevity, I've looked at `NullReferenceException` solutions for my problem but none have worked.

Comment: You have not even shown you `Assignments()` method! And use `new { coursename = Model.CourseName }`. But do not use a `<button>` with `onclick`. Use a link (and style it to look like a button if that is what you want)

Comment: And `return View(assignment.CourseName);` in your POST method makes no sense. It would need to be `return View(assignment);`

Comment: The 'Assignments()' in the controller takes a single string value not a full model, and I just added the code for it. I have another form that has nearly the same code, but it doesn't take a parameter

Comment: That's the GET method, not the POST method (whose parameter is `CreateAssignmentModel assignment`). You not redirecting in the POST method, your returning the View so you need to return the model with it (and what you have shown would cause a different exception because your would not have a view with the same name as your `CourseName` property

Comment: Okay that solved the issue of the buttons, I replaced `return View(assignment); ` with `return RedirectToAction("Assignments","Session",new {assignment.CourseName});` and im getting the 'NullReferenceException'

Comment: You should use `new { courseName = assignment.CourseName }`. But what line of code is throwing that exception? You need to debug your code.

Comment: And your POST method code needs to be `if (!ModelState.IsValid){ return View(assignment); } return RedirectToAction(....);` - you do not use `ModelState.Clear()` when you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid - you would loose all the error messages

Comment: The exception is caught in my `StoredProcedure` class because the value that is passed into `Assignments(courseName)` is the value used in the stored procedure, and it fails because it is null

Comment: Create an input in your form for the `CourseName` property so it posts back a value

Comment: That worked! Thank you, sorry for all the small problems, I'm learning most of this on my own, my professor didn't have time to cover too much.

Comment: @keiro Add an condition while generating button if [ Model.CourseName ] is not null then only generate but else do not generate

Comment: I didn't even think of that, thank you.